# Why curve modifier goes in different direction

Tags: modifiers

I have a mesh and a curve modifier. I want that mesh to be coil on the curve. Sorry to say i never understood how the curve modifier works. When ever added it goes in different direction or away from the target. Can anybody explain me why my mesh going different direction other then the target curve.

[image]

[image]

**Mesh getting narrow on top and getting mix with each other**
[image]

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos my curve is not made from mesh. Its the spiral curve addon comes default with addon

Comment: Yes, I understand, but that makes no difference

Answer (score 2):

The curve and the object have to have their origins in the same place, otherwise you will see an offset and get unexpected results.

Snap ( <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> the cursor to the curve, and then snap the object to the cursor.

Then the deformation can take place corectly.

[image]

Note that the origin of the deformed object will be placed at the first control point of the curve.

Comment: Thanks for replying. A little conical shape at the top not similar fashion its going in curve

Comment: Mesh getting narrow on top and getting mix with each other