# I cannot get this cylinder to follow the bezier curve

Tags: bezier-curves

[image]

Hello guys, new to blender here. I cant seem to get this cylinder to follow the bezier curve spiral shape i created. When I move the cylinder along the curve its completely off and starts twisting and bending like crazy.

I used the curve modifier on the cylinder and as the object i chose the bezier curve. I already matched the centers of both objects as well along the x,y, and z. And for the curve modifier the deformation axis is set to X.

Any help would truly be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: please add some detail about how you setup the cylinder to follow the curve. probably easiest way would be using the bezier curve as bevel object of a curve circle...

Comment: Please ... Improve your question by showing  the settings for the Curve Modifier if you have one.  Make more effort to be clear.    Curve modifiers typically are active along only one axis. X, Y, Z . Try all three separately.  Know the location of both object centers.

Comment: Aside from what is already said, start from recalculating normals and applying scale for the cylinder

Comment: Wouldn't the easiest thing to do here, to simply apply the curve as a solidified mesh?

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/80872/how-can-i-duplicate-an-object-along-a-path/80883#80883 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81523/why-curve-modifier-goes-in-different-direction/81546#81546

Comment: I used the curve modifier on the cylinder and as the object i chose the bezier curve. I already matched the centers of both objects as well along the x,y, and z

Answer (score 2):

see what I suggested above it could help, perhaps

set a bezier curve, and a little curve circle

[image]

then set the curve circle as bevel object of the bezier:

[image]

when finished (perhaps better keep a copy) you can convert to mesh with <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>

edit: adding a less linear bezier

[image]

or a real spiral (see [How to make flat spirals](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/79764/how-to-make-flat-spirals))

[image]

Comment: The problem with this method is that it doesn't work well for sharper turns. For example, create a vertical bezier circle. Scale it to say 8:1 (8 vertically, 1 horizontally), so it becomes more of an oval with the sharper points at the top and bottom. Then, apply a small circle bevel object to it as you proposed in your answer to make the elongated circle into more of a 3D loop (or hose loop). Notice how at the elongated portions of the former circle (top/bottom), the diameter is different than at the more flat parts. The diameters are inconsistent and mismatch the Bevel Object.

Comment: Continued... What's really needed is a technique that works well for beziers with sharp (but still round, of course) curves as well as very loose curves like your sample image in the answer. All of these techniques that use a Bevel Object so solve this problem use a bezier curve with very large circular turn radii (i.e., no fairly steep turns) to dodge the issue I described. Is there a solution for steeper turns that look more like fairly elongated asymmetric ovals.

Comment: I just increased the depth of the bezier curve and that created a cylinder following the curve. Its the only thing I could figure out. Thanks for the help

Comment: ok, if it works well for you, it's good. I just added some more complicated examples, just for fun...

Comment: @MichaelGoldshteyn lol your comment is exactly why i ended up here